# Blazor C# .Net 6.0 oData $metadata: Generated Proxy Vs typed HttpClient

Tags: c#, blazor, odata, httpclient, metadata

I have a Blazor Server .net 6.0 app that I wish to consume a number of API's in.

One SOAP API is setup using the Service Reference wizard and has built the proxy class and models and I can use this without issue.

I have two more that are oData based, I've managed to query both using HttpClient - for which one uses oAuth 2.0 bearer tokens, the other basic authentication.

I am able to query various functions on both oData feeds and get a valid JSON string returned. The issue I'm having is understanding the data models around them.

For one of them I created my own data model class and manually replicated the models (there is not much being offered by this API). I can successfully deserialise the JSON response to my manually typed model (although for single items I deserialise direct to the model (EmployeeModel) for lists I had to add a second class (ODataEmployeeModel) to strip out the JsonProperty("odata.context") string) like so

```
public class ODataEmployeeModel
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.context")]
    public string? Metadata { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeModel>? Value { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string? DisplayId { get; set; }
    public string? Title......
}
```

The other is a well-developed API offing a lot of data documented in the $metadata including complex models. What is the best way to consume the $metadata?

I was hoping that I could scaffold classes to match the models / entities much like scaffolding from a database using EF but most of my reading (or at least my understanding of my reading) seems to indicate that I should add NuGet package and generate a proxy class and the data classes for the service all in one go.

This I assume this would mean that my own HttpClient code is moot? What (if any) is the preferred / better way to connect? I will be using various filters etc.. on the oData requests and I have these working perfectly with my typed HttpClient setup.........

Is the generated proxy from a plugin like [ODataV4ClientGenerator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator) the better way of doing things?

Any help / suggestions / guidance is much apricated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dynamic` type if you don't know what the object looks like.

Assuming the API returns a JSON object.

```cs
class Response
{
    public int IKnowThisField { get; set; }
    public dynamic ButIDontKnowThis { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.Deserialize<Response>(data);
```

Comment: Thanks - at the moment I am only starting to look at what I can achieve with this new API and I know it provides the data I currently want - I can look at the $metadata from the source and build a class to match the oData entity in my program, meaning I can then target within my code the specific bit of the returned data I want with ease. If I use type dynamic then how could I reference a specific part of the returned entity within my code? I'm guessing it won't compiler as it doesn't explicitly know the makeup of each returned dieselised entity?

Comment: The idea of a `dynamic` is that it doesn't matter. Try assigning your `ODataEmployeeModel` to a `dynamic` and add a breakpoint there to inspect it with the debugger. It will show you how to access the variables etc.

Comment: Apologies I clearly need a coffee (it's early here) for some reason I was thinking you meant that using dynamic would map the class out for me as opposed to just a placeholder for an unknown variable type within a class. Based on this I would still be required to build the class manually - which is fine it is just that there are 86 classes and 2362 variables within these classes returned. I have all the details of the classes including variable types I am wondering what the best way is to create the classes within my program to deserialse to.

Comment: Good morning then! I see what you want. You could try to generate the code, with more code, so you don't have to type all of it. Other than that, I have no idea, besides just typing it all in.